# R-how to fill Array with data from 36 files

Tags: arrays, r, multidimensional-array, field, fill

Im having a problem filling a 3D Array with my data.

What I want to do:
I have 36 ".nc" files with a variable  where I count the values >x for 24 time steps. Those 36 .nc should be shown as the Matrix (bycol or row) x 24hours.
My Array should therefore have dim (6,6,24). My problem is that my code so far only fills one Value for each 6x6. But at least i have 24 different values.

I have tried different approaches but this is my latest code:

```
Data<- array(NA,dim=c(6,6,24))



for (j in 0:36) {
nc=open.ncdf(paste("/xxxx/Data#",j,".nc",sep=""))

Var=get.var.ncdf (nc,"Var")
close(nc)

for (k in 1:6) { 
for( l in 1:6)      {
for(i in 1:24)          {

Data[k,l,i]<- (sum(Var[,,i]>x)) 
            }
        }       
}
```

I have also tried:

```
Data[,,i]<- (sum(Var[,,i]>x))
```

without the k,l loops but this doesnt work either.

Thank you in advance!

BRGDS,
Genesis

Comment: you are missing a `}` in the `j`loop. Also, please provide some reproducible data, see stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610

Comment: Is `Var[,,i]` a single  value? in which case `sum(Var[,,i]>x)` is only ever 0 or 1? Can you describe what you want `Data` to be? Are you after a 6x6 matrix where `Data[i,j]` counts how many times `Var` was greater than `x` for that `i,j`? Or a 6x6x24 matrix where `Var[i,j,k]` is ..... ?